# Is this ruby property called "Open Class"?Is there any other language have this property?

Tags: ruby

```
class A
    def p
        puts "1"
    end
end

a = A.new
a.p   #=> "1"

class A
    def p
        puts "2"
    end
end

a.p   #=>"2"
```

Is this ruby property called "Open Class"?Is there any other language have this property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is called *open class* in Ruby. Off the top of my head, other languages which have this property include Python and Smalltalk. Also, even though they don't have classes, mutating a prototype object in ECMAScript, Self, Io and Ioke will have a similar effect.

Comment: Python doesn't really have open classes, does it?

Comment: A class is really just a dictionary of methods and a pointer (or in Python a list of pointers) to the superclass(es). In Ruby, that's hidden away from you, which is why you need special syntax to re-open a class. In Python, the method (or attribute) dictionary is made available to the programmer, so, in some sense, Python classes are even *more* open than Ruby classes: `class A(object):
    def p(__self__):
        print("1")

a = A()

a.p()

def p2(__self__):
    print("2")

A.p = p2

a.p()
` (Imagine proper formatting :-) or see [this Gist](https://Gist.GitHub.Com/2499065/))

Comment: thanks for your reply,in fact this question is pre-question of another one,will you answer this please?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335680/is-the-parasitic-combination-inheritance-copied-the-prototype-of-the-superclass

Comment: @JörgWMittag: there's something about the way you're putting it that makes me imagine it's not 100% correct, but I'm not able to put my finger on it.

Comment: whoops, hit enter too quickly. In Ruby I might say it's *less* hidden away; the class object is in every sense a full object, it has its own metaclass, and you define methods on the class itself just like you can on a normal object's metaclass.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are ways to do this in Smalltalk, I would tend to ask why you feel you want to do it and push for a different solution.  Changing code at runtime is a recipe for making difficult code to debug.